# Flutter: ComputelineMetrics not Behaving as Expected in RTL (Right-to-Left) Text Direction

Tags: flutter, dart, text, right-to-left, arabic-support

I'm working on a mobile app in Flutter that splits a long text into pages and presents it as book pages. I am facing a problem in languages like Arabic, whose TextDirection is RTL. Half of the lines at the bottom of the screen are cut off and do not appear completely.

The expected correct result should be:

[image]

The actual result looks like this:
[image]

It shouldn't be the line at the bottom of the screen. This line should have moved to the next page, as there was not enough space at the bottom of the screen.

My codes are as follows:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

const sampleText = '''
عد أسابيع من الشد والجذب، منح الاتحاد الأوروبي أخيراً الاثنين موافقته على استثناء السيارات التي تعمل بالوقود التركيبي من الحظر الذي يعتزم تطبيقه على بيع السيارات ذات محركات الاحتراق بحلول عام 2035، بعد رفع ألمانيا تحفظها عن النسخة الأولى من ورقة الاتفاق.
وعارضت برلين بشدة هذا الحظر، تخوفاً من أن تقضي السياسات البيئية الأوروبية على صناعة السيارات الألمانية. فيما يعد قرار الاتحاد الأخير أول اعتراف سياسي بالوقود التركيبي مصدر طاقة أخضر، بعدما دافع عن حياده الكربوني عدد من الخبراء والمهندسين المختصين.
ما الوقود التركيبي؟
يعد الوقود التركيبي، كالبنزين التركيبي والكيروسين التركيبي والميثان التركيبي، وقوداً غير أحفوري. بل يُصنَّع عن طريق تجميع انبعاثات ثاني أكسيد الكربون وأحادي أكسيد الكربون التي التُقطت في الجو، والهيدروجين الأخضر المنتَج باستخدام كهرباء متجددة أو خالية من الانبعاثات.
ويجادل خبراء البيئة بحياده الكربوني، لأن تصنيعه يستهلك تقريباً نفس كميات ثاني أكسيد الكربون وأحادي أكسيد الكاربون التي يطلقها في أثناء انبعاثه. بالإضافة إلى أن الهيدروجين المستخدم فيه يجب أن يكون خالياً من الانبعاثات.
وتراهن شركات النفط وصناعة السيارات على استعمال هذا النوع من الوقود، والذي سيمنح نشاطها التجاري أمد حياة أطول في ظل تغير السياسات العالمية نحو الطلاق مع الوقود الأحفوري.
ومع ذلك، لم يُشرع بعد في إنتاج الوقود التركيبي على نطاق واسع. وافتُتح أول مصنع تجاري في العالم لهذا الوقود في تشيلي عام 2021، بدعم من شركة بورش، ويهدف إلى إنتاج 550 مليون لتر سنوياً. فيما تشمل المصانع الأخرى المخطط لها Norsk e-Fuel النرويجية، التي من المقرر أن تبدأ الإنتاج في عام 2024 مع التركيز على وقود الطائرات.
ويجادل مؤيدو الوقود التركيبي بأنه سبيل لخفض انبعاثات ثاني أكسيد الكربون مع الحفاظ على أسطول السيارات الحالي، دون عناء استبدال كل مركبة بأخرى كهربائية. كما يمكن لهذا الوقود أن يكون حلاً أخضر في بعض قطاعات النقل، كالطائرات وسفن الشحن، التي يصعب تشغيلها بالكهرباء.
أمل السيارات الأوروبية
وعرقلت ألمانيا بشدة توصل دول الاتحاد الأوروبي إلى اتفاق حول حظر السيارات التي تعمل بالوقود الأحفوري بحلول عام 2035، مصرة على استثناء الوقود التركيبي من هذا الحظر.
وسبق أن دافع وزير النقل فولكر فيسينغ، عن تشبث بلاده باستثناء الوقود التركيبي، بالقول: "نحن في ألمانيا نتقن تكنولوجيا محركات الاحتراق أفضل من أي أحد في العالم، ومن المنطقي إبقاء هذه التكنولوجيا في أيدينا فيما تظل بعض الأسئلة حول التنقل المحايد مناخياً بلا إجابة".
ويمنح قرار الاتحاد الأوروبي الاثنين القاضي باستثناء الوقود التركيبي من الحظر الذي يزمع تطبيقه بحلول عام 2035، أملاً لاستمرار صناعة السيارات الأوروبية. فيما لو مرّ قرار الحظر دون استثناء، كان ليخلق متاعب كبيرة لصناعة السيارات الأوروبية، وعلى رأسها الألمانية. وذلك لمشكلات التنافسية التجارية التي ستخلقها، إذ سيتعذر على الشركات الألمانية إنتاج سيارات كهربائية بأسعار مناسبة للسوق التي تشهد منافسة صينية وأمريكية كبيرة.
وهو ما يؤكده مقال لمجل "فوربس" الأمريكية، بالقول إن "المصنعين الأوروبيين في السوق المشتركة، مثل فولكس فاجن الألمانية وعلاماتها التجارية الرئيسية، سيكونون الضحايا الرئيسيين لهذا القرار الأوروبي".
وتشهد السيارات الكهربائية الصينية نمواً كبيراً في أوروبا، إذ بلغ رقم معاملاتها عام 2022 حوالي 3.2 مليار دولار، أي بارتفاع قدر بنسبة 165% عن عام 2021. وبالتزامن مع ذلك، تواصل الولايات المتحدة في تنفيذ إجراءات خفض التضخم، والتي تحفز المستهلك المحلي على شراء السيارات الأمريكية الصديقة للبيئة بتوفير دعم حكومي لمُصنّعي هذا النوع من السيارات.
وبالإضافة إلى التنافسية، توجد عراقيل أخرى تترصد صناعة السيارات الألمانية، وهي قصر المدة الزمنية الممنوحة من أجل التحول إلى صناعة السيارات الكهربائية، كذلك تكلفة هذا التحول. وفي هذا الإطار، احتجت "الجمعية الأوروبية لمصنعي السيارات"، معتبرة قرار الاتحاد "متسرعاً"، إذ "بالنسبة إلى تحول صناعي بهذا الحجم، يعد هذا أمراً غير مسبوق ويشكل مصدر قلق بالغ".
ورحبت مجموعة "فولكس فاغن" بقرار استثناء الوقود التركيبي من الحظر، وقالت في بيان: "نرى أن الوقود الإلكتروني إضافة مفيدة للأسطول الحالي من السيارات ذات محركات الاحتراق، كما هو مفيد للتطبيقات الخاصة مثل سيارات الطوارئ أو السيارات الرياضية المحدودة كطراز "بورش 911" على سبيل المثال".
''';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: PagingTextScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class PagingTextScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PagingTextScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PagingTextScreen> createState() => _PagingTextScreenState();
}

class _PagingTextScreenState extends State<PagingTextScreen> {
  ///
  final List<String> _pageTexts = [];

  ///
  final _pageKey = GlobalKey();

  ///
  final textStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30);

  ///
  int _currentPage = 0;

  ///
  void _paginate(String text, TextStyle textStyle) {
    final pageSize =
        (_pageKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size;

    debugPrint('Page Size: $pageSize');

    _pageTexts.clear();

    final textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: text,
      style: textStyle,
    );

    ///
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: textSpan,
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    );

    ///
    textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: pageSize.width,
    );

    List<LineMetrics> lines = textPainter.computeLineMetrics();
    double currentPageBottom = pageSize.height;
    int currentPageStartIndex = 0;
    int currentPageEndIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      final line = lines[i];

      final left = line.left;
      final top = line.baseline - line.ascent;
      final bottom = line.baseline + line.descent;

      if (currentPageBottom < bottom) {
        currentPageEndIndex =
            textPainter.getPositionForOffset(Offset(left, top)).offset;
        final pageText =
            text.substring(currentPageStartIndex, currentPageEndIndex);
        _pageTexts.add(pageText);

        currentPageStartIndex = currentPageEndIndex;
        currentPageBottom = top + pageSize.height;
      }
    }

    final lastPageText = text.substring(currentPageStartIndex);
    _pageTexts.add(lastPageText);

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _initPagination() async {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _paginate(sampleText, textStyle);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initPagination();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('computeLineMetrics test')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: SizedBox(
                key: _pageKey,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                     return Text(
                      _pageTexts[index],
                      style: textStyle,
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: _pageTexts.length,
                  onPageChanged: (pageNumber) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentPage = pageNumber;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Text(
                    '${_currentPage + 1} / ${_pageTexts.length}',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tested it by switching to Flutter master channel, but nothing changed. I couldn't solve the problem.

Flutter (Channel master, 3.9.0-22.0.pre.11, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of what happens and make another image of what it should look like if it were working correctly?

Comment: Thank you. I have attached screenshots for actual result and expected result.

Comment: Hmm, so you are expecting 15 lines but you are getting 16 or more lines and the 16th line is cut off. Since you only want 15 lines (or x lines for some available height), I wonder if you could just count out that many lines. My brain isn't working enough today to figure out what your current logic is doing. Let me add a bounty and see if someone else will take a try at solving it.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.  Actually, what I want to achieve is to paginate a long article to fit the dimensions I have specified.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is occurring because you're not considering the line height when computing the available space for the text. This results in the last line being cut off when it doesn't fit in the available space. You can fix this issue by taking the line height into account when checking if there is enough space for the text on the current page.

Modify the `_paginate` function to account for the line height:

```dart
void _paginate(String text, TextStyle textStyle) {
  final pageSize =
      (_pageKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size;

  debugPrint('Page Size: $pageSize');

  _pageTexts.clear();

  final textSpan = TextSpan(
    text: text,
    style: textStyle,
  );

  ///
  final textPainter = TextPainter(
    text: textSpan,
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  );

  ///
  textPainter.layout(
    minWidth: 0,
    maxWidth: pageSize.width,
  );

  List<LineMetrics> lines = textPainter.computeLineMetrics();
  double currentPageBottom = pageSize.height;
  int currentPageStartIndex = 0;
  int currentPageEndIndex = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    final line = lines[i];

    final left = line.left;
    final top = line.baseline - line.ascent;
    final bottom = line.baseline + line.descent;

    // Add line height to bottom
    final lineHeight = line.height;
    final adjustedBottom = bottom + lineHeight;

    if (currentPageBottom < adjustedBottom) {
      currentPageEndIndex =
          textPainter.getPositionForOffset(Offset(left, top)).offset;
      final pageText =
          text.substring(currentPageStartIndex, currentPageEndIndex);
      _pageTexts.add(pageText);

      currentPageStartIndex = currentPageEndIndex;
      currentPageBottom = top + pageSize.height;
    }
  }

  final lastPageText = text.substring(currentPageStartIndex);
  _pageTexts.add(lastPageText);

  setState(() {});
}
```

This should fix the issue with the last line being cut off when there is not enough space at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Hey, this is an experiment. This answer was produced by GPT-4. In case it actually works, there is no need to send me the 200 rep!

Comment: @MarcG, I don't mind awarding the bounty to you since it provided a working answer (according to the asker), but currently [SO is temporarily banning ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) answers so the bounty may get taken away. My own opinion is that as long as the answerer verifies the validity of the answer, then it could be accepted. On a large scale, though, that's hard to enforce. In any case, I have to wait a few more hours before the system lets me award the bounty.

Comment: @MarcG,  I changed the font size (from 30 to 26) and ran into a few different issues. 1- Unnecessary spaces appear at the bottom of the screen. 2- Although there is enough space, only half of the line at the bottom of the screen is visible. The other half of the row goes to the next page.

You can see it in the screenshot:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8548639/231016374-37e9e817-fafb-4f4a-808d-faefdcfc5ee1.png

Comment: @Suragch Ah, I didn't know it was banned. Maybe I should delete this?

Comment: @burhanaksendir It was difficult for me to verify this, since I don't know Arabic. However, maybe this is another issue entirely? See this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15465

Comment: @MarcG I think it is still a valuable answer. I wouldn't delete it unless SO asks you to. I was also thinking something along the lines of (no pun intended) calculating the combined line heights for each page.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution. I also tried using ParagraphBuilder instead of TextPainter, but the result is still incorrect.